# Stop GNU Emacs (GUI) on macOS from quitting

Tags: osx, gui-emacs, quitting

Is it possible to stop Emacs on macOS from quitting? This may sound like a weird request, but numerous times I may accidentally quit Emacs and the whole GUI app exits -- which means I then have to restore the session as it was before (which is a pain).

Or maybe there's another way to solve this problem: is it possible to have Emacs' session restore to exactly where it was when the app quit?

Comment: Maybe edit your question to make clear from the outset that you want to avoid/prevent accidentally quitting, not prevent being able to quit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. See `kill-emacs-query-functions`, which lets you query yourself to confirm quitting, to avoid accidental quitting.
2. See `desktop.el`, which lets you save most of the state of your session when you quit, and restores it at the next session. See the Emacs manual, node [Saving Emacs Sessions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html). See also `savehist.el` and bookmarks.

Comment: You may also try to modify the "app" launcher for emacs to use emacsclient and daemon.

Comment: You may also try to modify the "app" launcher for emacs to use emacsclient and daemon. It should say something along the lines emacsclient -c || ( emacs --daemon && emacsclient -c)

Answer (score 1):

You may consider setting `(setq confirm-kill-emacs 'yes-or-no-p)` as described in

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Exiting.html

> One convenient function to use as the value of confirm-kill-emacs is
>   the function yes-or-no-p. The default value of confirm-kill-emacs is
>   nil.

And if you only want this to apply in the GUI version of MacOS, and not in Terminal, then you can use:
`(when (display-graphic-p) (setq confirm-kill-emacs 'yes-or-no-p))`